# Multiple UI for a single ListBox in Wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have a listbox in the xaml page.I have created three tabs(Normal text boxes) on the top.If clicked on tab 1 or tab 2,it displays an expander view in the listbox as its item.I want to create a simple listbox for the 3rd tab,i.e, no expander view.Is it possible in wp8?

Comment: Maybe you can make your question more clear, I'm having a hard time imagining your problem

Comment: I want to create two different types of UI for the same listbox.If I click on first tab it should show an expander view and if i click on the second tab it should show a normal list of items.Creating tabs is not an issue.I just want to know if their is a way to create two different types of list box items in a single listbox.Is it clear now?

Answer (score 0):

I not sure that I understand your question, but I think that you could use a Pivot control to achieve the results you want to get.

Using a Pivot, you could get different "tabs" and each tab could have his own controls. Hope this helps